# Stock Splits Question on ProShares UltraPro QQQ

Tags: nasdaq, leveraged-etf

What am I doing wrong here? The price of 1 share of $TQQQ was $0.43 in Feb 2010, today the price of 1 share of $TQQQ is $ 54.76, and the stock has split as follows

- 02/25/2011 2 for 1;
- 05/11/2012   2 for 1;
- 01/24/2014   2 for 1;
- 01/12/2017   2 for 1;
- 05/24/2018 3 for 1;
- 01/21/2021   2 for 1;
- 01/13/2022   2 for 1.

So, if someone had bought a single share of TQQQ in Feb 2010 for $0.43 would it be worth $10513.92 (1x2x2x2x2x3x2x2x54.76) today?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most (many? all?) sites adjust their historical prices to account for stock splits. They do this because a split doesn't change the value of your investment.  If there's a 2 for 1 stock split, it halves share price and doubles the amount of shares. Or the opposite if there's a reverse split.

If they didn't adjust for the splits, there would be a big drop in the price chart and it would look like the company/fund was doing poorly. In a reverse split there would be a big jump in price that would make it seem like there was an actual huge jump in share price.

Comment: All US equities are adjusted for stock splits and dividends.

Answer (score 0):

When a stock split occurs, share price is adjusted based on the size of the split.

For example, if XYZ closed at $100 yesterday and split 2:1 today, share price would be $50 today, before trading resumed.  Historically, you'll see $50 as the high price, even though it traded at $100.  If it splits 2:1 again, that adjusted historical price would become $25. And so on for additional splits.

Here's a rough estimation: Given that there have been six 2:1 splits and one 3:1 split, one share owned in 2010 would be 192 shares today. Therefore, the price back then should be in the ball park of today's price divided by 192 which is $55/192 or 29 cents.

This number is low because TQQQ has paid 13 dividends since 2010 and this is unaccounted for in this calculation. This guesstimation is merely to demonstrate why after all of these stock splits, the adjusted share price is so low (43 cents).